# Adding gestures for UIImageView and UIView at one ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Newbie question.
In IB I added UIImageView to scene and set few gestures for it in `-viewDidLoad` this way:

```
image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
image.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(controlPan:)];
[image addGestureRecognizer:pan];

pan.delegate = self;
// and few others gestures same way
...
```

and gestures worked fine. After that in IB I added UIView to the same scene and implement gestures absolutely identically to previous code, again in `-viewDidLoad`. But after that gestures stop working for both UIView and UIImageView. Do I need to make .h and .m for this view and to implement gesture recognizers there, or reason can be in something else?

Comment: Do you have set the same method for UIView and UIImageController here: action:@selector(controlPan:)? If yes, then try setting different handler methods.

Comment: Yes they was all connected to the same method. I tried to connect to another and now it worked! Thank you very much! But why was gestures blocked before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have same handler method you need to make distinction from which object gesture came, so you can properly handle action. If you set different handler methods for every object you dont have to care from which object gesture was invoked.